# How do you call a method from a catch block in java?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

**Requirement:** If there are any exceptions, call a method that re verifies data

**My implementation:**

```
private void one() {
    try {
        //Valid data
    }catch(Exception e) {
    two();
    }
}

private void two() {
     //Process data with another input
     //On entry,
     one();
}
```

I realize that my usage is incorrect. How should I be handling this?

Comment: Why do you think this is "incorrect"?

Comment: I hope this is not a case of catch clause becoming a "second try". Please could you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: The reason why I think is incorrect is: there is one more if condition in the catch block which has **if(error)System.exit(0);**
So, once I call one() from the catch block, the previous error value still exists. Hence it exits the application

Comment: @dkulkarni, Check my answer again, after your above comment I have edited it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it exactly the way you suggest, using recursion.  I don't see what the problem is. Personally, using a loop is usually simpler than using recursion. I wouldn't just catch all Exception's however.  You are likely to want to handle different exceptions differently.

```
private void one() {
  while(true) {
    try {
        //Valid data
        break;
    }catch(InvalidArgumentException e) { // or what ever you expect.
        two();
    }
  }
}

private void two() {
     //Process data with another input
     //On entry,
}
```

or even

```
private void one() {
  while(true) {
    try {
        //Valid data
        break;
    } catch(InvalidArgumentException e) { // or what ever you expect.
        // Process data with another input
        // On entry,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that the usage was right. I was just not handling another condition well.

Answer (score 1):

Better way of doing it would be,
Check data in a while loop somewhere else before you use data in method `one()`,
While it's not valid keep correcting until it's valid and than give it to `one()`.

**After your comments in question**

make your `error` variable to be an class level and reset it in method `two()` like this,

```
private void two() {
     this.error = false;
     //Process data with another input
     //On entry,
     one();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: That is the "verify first" vs "try and let it crash" argument. I guess it depends on how frequent you think invalid input will be. There is some cost to verification that turned out to be unnecessary.

Comment: @SkeetOverFlow - Yes, this looks like a more optimal way of handling the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The usage you showed in the code is correct - What makes you think this is not correct ?

However, I see that you are recalling the original method in the catch on which I have comments -

1. If it keeps on throwing the exception, it will lead to Stack overflow.
2. You would like to have some preventive / different logic to check unless this is time dependent or the per-conditions changed itself during the calls.
3. You should consider an exit condition in case you stuck into loop.